# Método de Armazenamento de Banco Local

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados

Possuo um banco local em meu desktop, nele fiz o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação utilizando `C#` e `Asp.Net MVC` e pensava que só teria o trabalho de migrar para algum banco MS SQL quando fosse fazer o upload do projeto.

Porém, necessito transferir os dados desse banco local para meu notebook para realizar a apresentação da minha aplicação.

A pergunta: Como é armazenado um banco local? É gerado um arquivo passivo a transferência? O método de autenticação acaba por ser autenticação do windows?

Comment: Depende de como você montou o banco local. A autenticação é a que você tiver configurado para ele. Já quanto aos arquivos, o que você quer dizer por "passivo a transferência"?

Comment: Entendo. Eu quis dizer algum arquivo o qual consigo encontrar em disco e transferir para outro computador no qual seja possível importar e/ou referenciar esse banco local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você tem o SQL Server instalado no laptop, o ideal é você fazer um backup do banco na máquina de desenvolvimento, e recuperar no notebook. É o procedimento recomendado e evita erros relacionados a referências que o SQL possa manter internamente aos objetos da base.

Em linguagem de DBA, você vai fazer um ***Detach*** na máquina de dev e um ***Attach*** no laptop. As instruções, nos mínimos detalhes, estão nos links abaixo da MSDN, separados por versão:

- [SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189624(v=sql.90).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189624(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2014](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189624.aspx)

Quanto a autenticação, é a que você tiver configurado. Se for autenticação via SQL e não lembrar a senha do SA, abra uma pergunta sobre como resetá-la, ok?